# How can I cut a large bathroom mirror?

Tags: mirror

Basically two small questions - Can I reasonably cut a large bathroom mirror and will doing so in that way look professional?

For the particular mirror in question we added higher vanity and need to take 8 inches off the top/bottom.  It is a basic thick bathroom mirror with no beveling.

Comment: Yes, it can be cut (unless it is tempered, if so it should be marked as such); yes you should take it to a glass shop and have a pro do it unless you are willing to lose it. A regular glass scoring tool will cut it but you have to score/cut the silvered coating on the back in the exact same line that you score the front. When you snap it you do not get a second chance.

Comment: Better solution may be to score _ONLY_ the back (but make sure you do score the glass, not just the silvering). If you have cut glass before, you know the procedure. If not, you may not want to risk learning on a large (hence more expensive to replace) piece. Taking it to a glass shop certainly has the advantage of being simpler and more reliable, and will probably be fairly cheap.